# Show that $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $f(X)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am having trouble on the following question.  Some help would be much appreciated.

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a proper injective continuous function.  Show that $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $f(X)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper continuous"?

Comment: It is proper and it is continuous.

Comment: OK. What do you mean by "proper function"?

Comment: inverse image of compact set compact

Comment: Hint: show that proper maps send closed sets to closed sets.

Comment: Hint: A map $f:X\to Y$ is closed if $Y$ is covered by (int$(A_i))_I$ and each restriction $f_i:f^{-1}(A_i)\to A_i$ is a closed map. In particular, a proper continuous map into a locally compact Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: I showed that is is a closed mapping, how does this help?

Comment: Each closed injective continuous function should be a homeomorphic embedding.